# JS-loaded Twitter share button doesn't render properly

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter

In my Rails app, I have an "infinite page" that loads more blog posts as you scroll down. On each blog post, there is a twitter share button. When the page first loads, all the "above-the-fold" share buttons load great; the button appears properly, and when you click it, the custom text for the tweet appears.

However, the share buttons that load as you scroll down don't work. When you scroll down and more blog posts load, the share button loses its styling (becomes just a plain link), and the custom text feature goes away (when you click it, it opens a blank twitter window, without the custom text).

Even when I load all the twitter JS under each button, it still doesn't work. Here's my button code:

```
    %a.twitter-share-button{"data-count" => "none", "data-text" => "#{post.title} (My new blog post!)", "data-url" => "http://www.example.com", :href => "https://twitter.com/share"} Tweet
    :javascript
        !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
```

Comment: Are you styling these link dynamically, or in static CSS?

Comment: It gets styled with the Twitter JS. All the button code is above, pasted from the twitter builder. The only thing I added was the haml ruby tags in `data-text`. I'm not overriding `.twitter-share-button` in my css or otherwise styling it.

Comment: According to Twitter, you don't want to do that: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button/faq#multiple-buttons. The code there doesn't do anything if there's already a twitter box on the page, so subsequent calls won't do anything.

Comment: This thread: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/6860 suggests that you need to do rather more work for dynamically-added twitter buttons.

Comment: @jimw, the solution is in the link you provided. Just need to do `twttr.widgets.load();` after the partials load. Feel free to add that as a solution.

Comment: Excellent, I'll do that now :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/6860, to add multiple Twitter buttons to a page dynamically, you need to use:

```
twttr.render();
```

after adding each group of buttons. This function will render all the buttons currently on the page.

Answer (score 2):

Update: With updated API, it should be

```
twttr.widgets.load()
```